# Encoding Speex with libavcodec (FFMpeg)?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, libavcodec, speex, libavformat

I successfully compiled **libavcodec** with **speex** enabled.
I modified example from FFMPEG docs to encode the sample audio into Speex.
But the result file cannot be played with VLC Player(which has Speex decoder).

Any tips?

```
static void audio_encode_example(const char *filename)
{
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int frame_size, i, j, out_size, outbuf_size;
    FILE *f;
    short *samples;
    float t, tincr;
    uint8_t *outbuf;

    printf("Audio encoding\n");

    /* find the MP2 encoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_SPEEX);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

   c= avcodec_alloc_context();

    /* put sample parameters */
    c->bit_rate = 64000;
    c->sample_rate = 32000;
    c->channels = 2;
    c->sample_fmt=AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;

    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open(c, codec) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* the codec gives us the frame size, in samples */
    frame_size = c->frame_size;
    printf("frame size %d\n",frame_size);
    samples =(short*) malloc(frame_size * 2 * c->channels);
    outbuf_size = 10000;
   outbuf =( uint8_t*) malloc(outbuf_size);

    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* encode a single tone sound */
    t = 0;
    tincr = 2 * M_PI * 440.0 / c->sample_rate;
    for(i=0;i<200;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<frame_size;j++) {
            samples[2*j] = (int)(sin(t) * 10000);
            samples[2*j+1] = samples[2*j];
            t += tincr;
        }
        /* encode the samples */
        out_size = avcodec_encode_audio(c, outbuf, outbuf_size, samples);
        fwrite(outbuf, 1, out_size, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    free(outbuf);
    free(samples);
    avcodec_close(c);
    av_free(c);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    avcodec_register_all();

    audio_encode_example(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Speex (I don't know it) by chance require a container format into which these frames are placed, with some kind of header? You're just taking the output of an encoder and dumping into a file without going through any formatting (`libavformat`).

Try encoding the same data into Speex using the `ffmpeg` command line utility and see if the resulting file plays.

I'm looking at some info at `www.speex.org` and it seems that `speex` data is put into `.ogg` files. The player you are using might not recognize raw Speex data, but only if it is wrapped in `.ogg`.

Though not a 100% definite answer, I hope this is of some help!

Comment: I was wondering, I used CODEC_ID_MP2, the result file did not need a container.I will try using a OGG container.